# Migrating WordPress-related Questions to Webmasters instead of WordPress Answers?

Tags: feature-request, moderation, wordpress-se

I've noticed recently several WordPress-related questions have been migrated to [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) instead of [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) *([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109792/how-do-i-remove-a-picture-from-my-wordpress-site)):*

[image: Screenshot of Closed Answer on StackOverflow]

And then, as expected they closed the answer over there because it was off topic:

[image: Screenshot of Closed Answer on Webmasters]

Anyway, I'm posting:

1. To make sure that the admins here are aware of [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), if they are not already,
2. To ask when WordPress Answers will get the *"migrate to"* capability *(since it seems you can currently migrate from SO to PW but not to WA)*, and
3. To suggest in the short term that rather than migrate a WordPress question to Pro Webmasters that you suggest that the OP asks the question on WA themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI: nothing can be migrated to wordpress.stackexchange.com until it's out of beta.

Comment: Update: moderators can now migrate to any site, and we already get a steady stream of WordPress questions from other sites.